# How do you add an Ajax.ActionLink with class button using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to create an Ajax.ActionLink with button class using jquery.

I'm using ActionLinks for a tag cloud, I can populate it and remove old tags, but I have trouble figuring out how to add new tags with the same ajax attached.

This is my Ajax.ActionLink:

```
<div name="TagsDiv" id="TagsDiv" >
@foreach (var tagItem in Model.Tags)
{
@Ajax.ActionLink(tagItem.Name, "DeleteTag", "Tag",
new { GameID = Model.Id, tagValue = tagItem.Name },
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" },
new { @class = "btn removeTag", @style= "margin: 10px"})
}
```

I am using the following form to make new tags:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateTagItem", "Tag", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
        {
                <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="currentGameId" id="currentGameId" />
                <input class="form-control has-success col-md-6" name="newTag" id="newTag" type="text" placeholder="Type new tag value here" data-val-required="field is required" data-val="true" value=""/>
                <button class="btn btn-success add" id="addNewTag" href="#TagsDiv" data-id="@Model.Id" data-url="@Url.Action("CreateDeletableTag", "Tag")" type="submit">Add New Tag</button>
            }
```

I'll exclude the controller methods and other services.

I can create tags in my db successfully and am using the following jquery+ajax to .append a Partial View to the tag cloud:

```
@*createtag view jquery+ajax*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addNewTag").on('click', function (e) {
            var _self = $(this);
            var dataUrl = _self.data('url');
            var gamei = _self.data('id');
            var tagval = $("#newTag").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: dataUrl,
                cache: false,
                data: { GameID: gamei, tagValue: tagval },
                success: function(e) {
                    var content = [];
                    content.push(e);

                    $('#TagsDiv').append(content.join(''));
                },
                error: function() {}
            });
            return;
        });
    });
```

The partial view contains only the Ajax.Action link from the start of this post.

I use a simple jquery to remove tags when clicked, but it doesn't seem to work with a Partial View.

```
$(".removeTag").click(function(e) {
        $(e.target).remove();
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code to add new tags ?

Comment: I am using a @foreach (var tagItem in Model.Tags) with the Ajax from above to populate the cloud. But then I need to append the same style of tags when I create them.

Comment: Ajax.ActionLink executes on server side and jQuery executes on client side. What are you trying to achieve ? You need to provide more information /code

Comment: where is the code for `when I create them` ?

Comment: Updated my initial question.

Comment: I simply want to do this without partial views, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean approach, without the Ajax.ActionLink html helper. You will write jquery code to remove and add new item. You will have total control on what code to execute.

```
<div id="TagsDiv">
@foreach (var tagItem in Model.Tags)
{
    <div>
          @tagItem.Name - @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveTag", 
                  "Home", new { @id = tagItem.Id,gameId=Model.EventId  }, 
                        new { @class = "removeMe" })
    </div>   

}
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="newTag"/>
    <input type="button" data-id="@Model.Id" data-url="@Url.Action("CreateTag")" 
                                                                             id="addTag"/>
</div>
```

This will render all the Tags in a div along with a remove link associated with it and the input fields for creating a new tag.

So let's now add some js code to add a new tag and remove a tag when user clicks on the remove link.

```
$(function() {    
    $(document).on("click", "a.removeMe", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _self = $(this);
        $.post(_self.attr("href"), function(res) {
            if (res.Status === "success") {
                _self.closest("div").remove();
            }
        })
    });

    $("#addTag").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _self = $(this);    
        var dataUrl = _self.data('url');
        var gamei = _self.data('id');
        var tagval = $("#newTag").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: dataUrl,
            cache: false,
            data: { GameID: gamei, tagValue: tagval },
            success: function(r) {
                if (r.Status === "success") {
                    //Build markup for new tag
                    var newItem = $("<div>" + tagval +
                        "-<a href='@Url.Action("RemoveTag", "Home")?id=" + r.TagId + 
                                  "&gameId=@Model.Id' class='removeMe'>Remove</a></div>");
                    $('#TagsDiv').append(newItem);
                }

            },
            error: function() {}
        });

    });
});
```

This assumes that your Action methods returns Json data like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveTag(int id,int gameId)
{
    // to do  : remove from db
    return Json(new { Status = "success" });
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTag(int GameID,string tagValue)
{
    //to do : Save to db
    // replace 34 with the newly created Tag Id
    return Json(new {Status = "success", TagId = 34});        
}
```

If you do not prefer to build the html markup in your javascript code, you might return a partial view which has the markup of tag item (with remove action link)